# Como posso transformar a $_SESSION para o nome de usuário?

Tags: php

estou com uma dificuldade, estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e no banco de dados na tabela usuários eu salvo um campo usuarios_ID que no caso pega a sessão e salva ela. está dessa forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai na outra tela de registro eu chamo salvando o usuario_ID de quem fez a ação no sistema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é na hora de exibir isso em uma tabela como eu faço para trazer o nome do usuário invés do usuario_id, pois toda vez que trago o usuario_id em um campo, vem como 1, 2, 3 e gostaria que viesse o nome correspondente ao número.

Comment: Você criou a relação entre as tabelas e criou as chaves estrangeiras?